# nodejs called from module

Tags: node.js

How can I tell that a script written in node is being called by require?

Answer (score 3):

From the [node docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module):

> ### Accessing the main module
>
> When a file is run directly from Node, require.main is set to its
>   module. That means that you can determine whether a file has been run
>   directly by testing
>
> ```
>  require.main === module
> ```
>
> For a file foo.js, this will be true if run via node foo.js, but false
>   if run by require('./foo').
>
> Because module provides a filename property (normally equivalent to
>   __filename), the entry point of the current application can be obtained by checking require.main.filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can check property `parent` of `module` object. If your module called by require `module.parent` will return caller module, otherwise `module.parent` is null.